# USB boot missing, USB works

Tags: boot, usb, usb-installation

I have made a bootable USB. I have made 100s of them before. I have a dual boot pc, Kali and Ubuntu.

I want to reinstall Kali from USB (alongside my UBUNTU), but the computer will not boot to USB anymore. Burning ISO to DVD is really absurd.

Why can't I boot to USB anymore?

USB is disabled in bios, yet I use the USB ports everyday. Everyday. It is an Ubuntu question.

I can't and won't install Ubuntu on my laptop if I know I'll lose USB boot. This isn't a BIOS question.

Comment: The answer is in your old question. USB is disabled in BIOS but just for booting. You have to set boot priority for USB not the hard disk.

Comment: If you don't know, you can just say you don't know. I'VE BEEN THRU THE BIOS INSIDE AND OUT.  It is disabled in the BIOS, including the boot priority list, yet i use it quite often. Read the question, know-it-all. I've looked at the boot order - in the bios - and the USB is disabled. I've looked at available 'devices' and USB is also disabled. This is not the first computer it has happened.

Comment: Well I would answer the question or someone else but I can't understand it. Answer this: If you have dual boot Kali and Ubuntu why do you want to reinstall Kali? Why can't you boot? What do you mean disabled? You mean you can't see it there? If you insert it in the USB port can you access it from Ubuntu? Can you access it from another computer? Did you try different USB? Different port?

Comment: Ubuntu and no other operating system have influence on the capability of your BIOS to boot USB media. Did you verify the boot order in BIOS and everything? What happens, when you want to boot from a USB drive? Any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

Disabling USB support in BIOS, doesn't (necessarily) mean, that USB support remains disabled, after the BIOS relinquished hardware control to the operating system. I replicated this behaviour in the past, when I had no USB media to boot from and wanted to speed up the BIOS stage of the boot process.

For your BIOS to interact with and boot from USB media, you need to enable USB support in BIOS.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Comment: He said it worked in the past and I don't think he manually disabled it in BIOS. It could just be something with the USB.

Comment: What is your interpretation of "USB is disabled in BIOS"?

Comment: When I read everything he wrote I think it only means that it's just not there.